# rspec's should_receive on a non-mock object?

Tags: rspec

Is it possible to call `should_receive` on a non-mock object?

If it is, I'm wondering why this test doesn't pass. `SiteStyle` has_many `images` and when I call `duplicate!` on a site_style, I want the `images` to call `duplicate` on themselves as well. The test fails. The actual images get duplicated though. Why is that?

**SiteStyle model:**

```
class SiteStyle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :name, :user
  has_many :images, :as => :imageable, :order => "position", :dependent => :destroy

  ...

  def duplicate!(user, *args)
    options = args.extract_options!
    to_site ||= Site.find(options[:site_id])
    dup_style = self.class.create :site_id => to_site.id, :name => name, :user_id => user.id
    self.images.each { |image| image.duplicate!(dup_style) }
    dup_style
  end

  ...
end
```

**SiteStyleSpec:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SiteStyle do
  ...

  describe "duplicate!(user, *args)" do
    before do
      @creator = User.make
      @site = Site.make
      @style = SiteStyle.make :site => @site, :user => @creator
    end

    ...

    it "should have a duplicate of the images" do
      @image = Image.make :imageable_type => @style.class.name, :imageable_id => @style.id
      @image.should_receive(:duplicate!).once
      @dup_style = @style.duplicate!(@creator)
    end
  end
end
```

**Error:**

```
Failures:
  ...

  2) SiteStyle duplicate!(user, *args) should have a duplicate of the images
     Failure/Error: @image.should_receive(:duplicate!).once
     (#<Image:0xc7b40d8>).duplicate!(any args)
         expected: 1 time
         received: 0 times
     # ./spec/models/site_style_spec.rb:83
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line here:

```
@image.should_receive(:duplicate!).once
```

Is working with only that specific @image instance, and calling should_receive only on it so that expectation doesn't transfer over to the image objects used inside the duplicate method (or any other place where an image is instantiated) even if it is the same record from the database.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this behavior... I mean to call should_receive on any instance of @image as long as it's the same record?

Comment: @AhmedFathy: This answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/14468456/2623544

Comment: @NikitaAvvakumov Thanks for the suggestion. I have seen that answer while searching indeed. Doesn't help in my case because I needed it to pick certain instances not all... Ended up splitting the test into 2 , one with the criteria achieved and one with it not achieved and used Model.any_instance.should_receive in the first and Model.any_instance.should_not_receive in the second :)