# RSpec test that a class method calls an instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I'm looking to test that a class method calls a specific instance method. Is there any way to do this? This is the best I've got, but it fails.

```
describe '#foo' do
  let(:job) { create :job }
  it 'calls job.bar' do
    job.should_receive(:bar)
    Job.foo
  end
end
```

I need to be sure that the right instance of job is called, not just any instance. I appreciate any help.

Comment: So this test is testing the the instance method `#foo` calles the instance method `#bar` on the same instance. You aren't testing class methods at all. Which one is supposed to be an method on the class?

Comment: Sorry about that. Typo. Fixed it.

Comment: Awesome, so how does `.foo` get the instance to call? Is it doing an activerecord `.find` or something like that?

Comment: Yep. (filling in space for minimum comment length.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use stubs on the method by which `.foo` gets the instance.

For instance:

```
describe '.foo' do
  let(:job) { create :job }
  it 'calls job.bar' do
    Job.stub(:find).and_return job
    job.should_receive(:bar)
    Job.foo
  end
end
```

What this does is ensures that the instance that you expect to have methods called on is the one that actually gets used by `.foo`.

You can add expectations or argument matchers to this, so:

`Job.should_receive(:find).with(job.id).and_return(job)`

Comment: That's fantastic. Thank you so much. Still learning to use RSpec. Don't have stuff like this quite down yet, but this works great.